# What does this exclamation mark mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider:

```
function F() {
    w = !0;
    return !1
}
```

Is this a special way of setting a boolean variable? Why did the author do this?

Context:

```
document.onmousedown = F;
```

What does this exclamation mark mean in JavaScript?

Comment: I don't recommend this approach as it's entirely unnecessary to negate hard coded values.

Comment: @TGH `!0` is `true` (a boolean).  Note that while `0 == false, 0 !== false`

Comment: @TGH I think the point of `!0` is to save two characters (`"!0".length` is 2 while `"true".length` is 4)

Comment: @Nirk returning a true/false as boolean should not take up any more space than the !0 approach. It wouldn't return "true" (4 chars) in any event unless a "true" string was hard coded. I guess there is a very minor difference in script size as you it would let you download less script code (less characters), but the memory footprint should be the same once downloaded

Comment: @TGH the point is that the size of the **source code** when you write `!0` is smaller compared to `true`.  That means less code needs to be sent over the network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of unnecessary prowess.  The code below is exactly the same:

```
function F() {
    w = true; //w = !0;
    return false //return !1
}
```

If you are using a good minification tool, which you should in production, clever programming to save a few bytes becomes unnecessary.

Comment: OTOH Perhaps this code came from a minifier.

Comment: @kojiro True.  I was quick to jump the gun in assuming the code did not come from a minified file.

Answer (score 2):

`w` is a variable from an outer scope. `!0` is `true` but only takes 2 bytes, so my guess is that the author wanted to set `w` to be true in the callback function and wanted to save bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The exclamation mark is a logical [NOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation) operator that will convert these values to Boolean and ensure Boolean types.

So `w` is assigned true and your return is false.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, 0 is a false value, and any non-zero value is true. The `!` is a logical 'not', so `!0` is 'not false', or 'true', while `!1` is 'not true', or 'false'.

As to why the author did this - I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

! is the negation operator.  !0 is true.  !1 is false.

Comment: *implies* isn't the right word. `!0` is exactly true. `!1` is exactly false.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a way to set a boolean. In this case the function will return `false`, because `1` can be evaluated to `true` and therefore its negation (`!`) would evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score -1):

`!` means "not".

The example you show doesn't make much sense, generally where you would use this is something like:

```
var visible = false;

$('#link').click(function () {
   visible = !visible;
});
```

In this case above, each click would 'toggle' the variable `visible`.