# Is there any reason to use !1 over false?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking through some javascript code, and In various places, the developer uses `!1`, like so:

```
var somevar = !1;
```

from my understanding `!1` is the same as `false`.

Is there any practical (whether it is to cover some edge case, performance, etc.) reason as to why they are using `!1` instead of `false`?

Comment: They probably drifted over from the C programming department.

Comment: You know what's shorter? `0`

Comment: compiling with javascript minify's or just being fancy

Comment: Some busy sites go to great lengths to save even a couple of bytes since it all adds up to bandwidth. I doubt there's much performance difference with modern  Javascript engines.

Comment: @sbat `0` and `false` are two different things.

Comment: so the most likely reason is just to save those few precious bytes? seems kind of overkill but I suppose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this exclamation mark mean in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129089/what-does-this-exclamation-mark-mean-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a few less bytes. People are crazy about minifying these days!

Comment: But 0 is `0`, not `false`. If you're doing certain kinds of operations, this makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

It's fewer bytes, true. However that's the kind of optimizations that **should be left to the compressor** itself and doesn't really belong in the source code as it makes the code less readable.

Comment: @Nirk It's not because worst practices exists that it makes this one acceptable.

Comment: @Nirk: Can't imagine why you'd think that `!function(){..}()` is a "worse sin" when it's a safer alternative. Also can't see how it's any less readable. "Not what I'm accustomed to" is not the same as "not readable".

Comment: @user2736012 Totally agree.

Comment: @Nirk "but somehow !0 is not as safe as false?" I guess you just proved that it's not by asking this question... `!0` is not `false`, it's `true`.

Comment: @Nirk: I made no comparison to `!0`. I'm saying `!function(){..}()` is a safer alternative to `(function(){})()`, so how can it be a worse sin, even granting that `!0` is not unsafe? Though as @plalx pointed out, your comment demonstrates the problem with that syntax. Good catch @plalx! :-)

Comment: Aren't we a little too significant about this?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no difference. You don't have any good reason to use it.

#### HA!!!!! It's slower!

```
var iterations = 100000000;

var start = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
  var somevar = !1;
}
var end = new Date() - start;
console.log('SCORE 1: ' + end);

// Result: 2634ms


var start = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
  var somevar = false;
}
var end = new Date() - start;
console.log('SCORE 2: ' + end);

// Result: 1979ms
```

#### I got multiple downvotes [among upvotes] because it's technically shorter [for smaller code], so I just had to do this for the performance do-gooders. Sorry.

Lastly, [from Jeff Atwood, none other.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html)

Comment: "smaller source" is a good reason, especially if you use it many times

Answer (score 0):

`!1` is three characters shorter than `false`.